# Deploy to Remote Server using Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

How does one deploy their code to a remote server using Visual Studio Online after a build completes?

My Google skills apparently are lacking today as I am not finding information on this anywhere.

Comment: I believe I will be able to accomplish what I need by adding a "Windows Machine File Copy" task to my build definition.   This is less than ideal as you must setup firewall rules to allow Windows File Sharing between your server and a dynamic pool of Azure IP addresses.   If you have Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate license, the Release Management route @MrHinsh pointed out below would be the better route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use release management which you get with VSO. If you download the release manager client for visual studio you can create a release pipeline with tge vNext template that lets you deploy to and number of environments remotely. This is called Agent-less deployment and will have a migration path to the new Release capability in TFS 2015 (and VSO when it hits)

Comment: When I try to create an environment, using the "New vNext: Standard"  option, and try to save it I get an error message saying Standard Environment creation is not supported in RM Preview"

Comment: Great, it looks like I can't use the Release Management Client because I "only" have Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: Poo.. I am not sure how the new RM tools will be licenced.